# Android keeps asking me to add a new or existing account after factory reset

Tags: factory-reset

I factory reset my android phone but now I can't get pass the  "Provide existing or new account" screen. It allows me to provide my existing account, we walk through the screens, I skip the credit card screen then it takes me back to the add account screen, so I already added like 3 accounts but it seems like is an infinite loop so what can I do?

Comment: Credit card screen?!?! What device and Android version is this?

Comment: @acejavelin Could be google wallet. It tends to be a bit annoying sometimes, when restoring from google cloud.